# I can't unpack the android firmware system.new.dat.br

Tags: android, firmware, unpack

I want to change some apk files in the firmware. I can't unpack it. It turned out to be unpacked by third-party services, but then, after the assembly, the firmware was not installed on the device. Please help me to disassemble the file system.new.dat.br and ideally, replace the file there along the path system\system\priv-app\CaroceanLauncher with a modified one, which is located in the folder in the archive "file to replace" and pack it back into system.new.dat.br . I will provide all the files and the replacement file below

[GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15X6BWQIOn7GAHABiTlS3iWScqXo-REIP/view?usp=sharing)

I tried a lot of ways from Andoid Kitchen to sdat2img it turned out to be a broken img

Windows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.